# Is there a way to make interface code run at runtime?

Tags: java, events, event-handling, game-engine

I am working on implementing event handling in a simplistic game engine that I am creating in Java. I am now struggling to figure out how I should register an object's event handlers. I am thinking that I might be able to make an interface that runs a line of code (`public void registerListener(Object listener)`) when the object is created. I am aware that interfaces cannot define a constructor, so I am seeking guidance as to how I should approach this. Right now, I have to call the previously mentioned line of code in the constructor of all the objects that have event handlers in them, and I think that using an interface or something similar to reduce repetition would be an ideal solution.

Below is the rest of the event-system code in case you would like to take a look. Thanks!

**EventManager class:**
In charge of maintaining the list of methods that will respond to an event. When registering a EventHandler, you pass a class in as the parameter, and it will find all methods with an @EventHandler() annotation and use the annotation value as the event type.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class EventManager
{
    private HashMap<Class<? extends Event>, ArrayList<Method>> eventCallbackMap;

    public EventManager()
    {
        this.eventCallbackMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public void dispatchEvent(Event event)
    {
        ArrayList<Method> callbacks = eventCallbackMap.get(event.getClass());

        if(callbacks == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        for(Method callback : callbacks)
        {
            //TODO: Invoke Method
        }
    }

    public void registerListener(Object listener)
    {
        for(Method method : listener.getClass().getMethods())
        {
            if(method.isAnnotationPresent(EventHandler.class))
            {
                Class<? extends Event> value = method.getAnnotation(EventHandler.class).value();

                if(eventCallbackMap.containsKey(value))
                {
                    eventCallbackMap.get(value).add(method);
                }
                else
                {
                    ArrayList<Method> callbacks = new ArrayList<>();
                    callbacks.add(method);

                    eventCallbackMap.put(value, callbacks);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Event class:**
Very barebones abstract class that all custom events will extend from. I would appreciate if you could let me know how I can improve this class, I would appreciate that.

```
package events;

public abstract class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
    }
}
```

**EventHandler class:**
The annotation that defines a method as an event responding method.

```
package events;

import java.lang.annotation.*;

@Documented
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface EventHandler
{
    Class<? extends Event> value();
}
```

Comment: I think you should remove the annotation (why is that used? reflection is not right here) and make a regular interface that defines EventHandler.  Then registerListener should take that type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should use an interface, and not annotations. A very quick sample might look like this. It's just a code sketch, not sure whether it will compile. There's room for improvement but it's the basic idea:

```
interface EventHandler
{
    Set<Event> eventTypes();
    void onEvent(Event event);
}

interface Event
{
    // used as a marker interface, but probably add some methods
}

enum MouseEvent implements Event
{
    ON_CLICK
    //... and whatever else
}

class OnClickEventHandler implements EventHandler
{
    public Set<Event> eventTypes()
    {
        Set<Event> events = new HashSet<>();
        events.add(MouseEvent.ON_CLICK);
        return events;
    }

    public void onEvent(Event event)
    {
        if (event == MouseEvent.ON_CLICK)
        {
            System.out.println("Mouse clicked");
        }
    }
}

class EventManager
{
    private final Map<Event, List<EventHandler>> handlers = new HashMap<>();

    public void registerListener(EventHandler handler)
    {
        for (Event eventType : handler.eventTypes())
        {
            handlers.putIfAbsent(eventType, new ArrayList<>());
            handlers.get(eventType).add(handler);
        }
    }

    public void dispatchEvent(Event event)
    {
        handlers.getOrDefault(event, Collections.emptyList())
            .forEach(handler -> handler.onEvent(event));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback. Also, thank you for introducing me to the `putIfAbsent()` and `getOrDefault()` function.